# How to write shorter code function type script using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

how can i write shorter code,i use formGroup with a select form and i have 5 input..when i choose value in the select only one input get the value of date.
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIlFr.png)

```
             listenEtat(value) {
             let d = Date.now()
             let date= moment(d).format('lll')

            if (value === "Contrat Cadre") {
              this.formClient.get('Date_StatQ').setValue('');
              this.formClient.get('Date_StatEs').setValue(date);
              this.formClient.get('Date_StatCp').setValue('');
              this.formClient.get('Date_StatCs').setValue('');
              this.formClient.get('Date_StatCC').setValue('');
             
            }
          if (value === "En service") {
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatQ').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatCC').setValue(date);
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatCp').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatCs').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatEs').setValue('');
            }
           if (value === "Contrat définitif") {
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatQ').setValue(date);
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatCC').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatCp').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatCs').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatEs').setValue('');
            }
           if (value === "Prospection") {
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatQ').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatCC').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatCp').setValue(date);
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatCs').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatEs').setValue('');
            }
          if (value === "Quotation") {
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatEs').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatCC').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatQ').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatCp').setValue('');
            this.formClient.get('Date_StatCs').setValue(date);
            }
          }
```

Comment: So much repetition.  DRY is your friend.

Comment: @duffymo DRY is the reason why the OP is looking for shorter code, they just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [reset](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset) the entire formGroup with the following code:

```
this.formClient.reset();
```

After that you can create a [Enum](https://www.sohamkamani.com/javascript/enums/) (enumeration) to match value with formGroup key:

```
enum DateTypes {
    Date_StatQ = 'Contrat Cadre',
    Date_StatEs = 'En service',
    Date_StatCp = 'Contrat définitif',
    Date_StatCs = 'Prospection',
    Date_StatCC = 'Quotation'
}
```

Finally your code will look like this

```
enum DateTypes {
    Date_StatQ = 'Contrat Cadre',
    Date_StatEs = 'En service',
    Date_StatCp = 'Contrat définitif',
    Date_StatCs = 'Prospection',
    Date_StatCC = 'Quotation'
}

this.formClient.reset();

const formControlName = Object.keys(DateTypes).find(key => DateTypes[key] === value);
this.formClient.get(formControlName).setValue(date);
```